# lxml, how to get raw attribute value with CRLF

Tags: python, attributes, whitespace, lxml

This is my small python program:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
tree = etree.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print root.attrib['a']
```

This is the test.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root a="line one
line two
line three">
</root>
```

When I run it I get:

```
line one line two line three
```

While I would expect:

```
line one
line two
line three
```

How to achieve the expected behaviour?

Comment: I don't think this could be achieved...,  why not make `line one, line two, line three` three separate attributes?

Comment: see the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#AVNormalize . as mentioned, you can't really put a newline in an attribute value - 'proper' support means replacing all whitespace with single spaces. edit: reading further, it looks like you may be able to use an attribute list, and declare the attribute CDATA, in which case it will work. never done it though, and there is probably a more straightforward method (don't even know if lxml will honor that anyways...)

Comment: @zhangxaochen: I'm given such (faulty?) xml, so I can't change its structure or contents.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) which is a great Python library for parsing semi-broken xml/html. E.g.:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
xml = open('test.xml').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)
print soup.root.attrs['a']
```

which prints:

```
line one
line two
line three
```